# Adding second approver in expense Approval report

Tags: workflow

I wanted to add a second approval in Expense report Approval. I have taken the script from [this tutorial](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/articles/expense_report_approval).

The condition is able to check state (1) if approved then send email to second approval, it is also able to put the MANAGER_EMAIL in state2 field. But it is failing to change the state2 to either "APPROVED" or "DENIED" so that it can trigger another email for DIRECTOR_EMAIL in state3 which is the final approval stage.

```
function onReportOrApprovalSubmit(row) {


    // This is the Procurement Approvals Spreadsheet
      var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
      var sheet = ss.getSheets()[0];
      var lastRow = sheet.getLastRow();

      // Set the status of the new request to 'New'.
      // Column O is the Status column
      sheet.getRange(lastRow,getColIndexByName("Status")).setValue("New");

      // Initialize open Procurement Request (Responses) spreadsheet for editing
      // This is the active spreadhseet since this script is stored with it.
      var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
      var sheet = ss.getSheets()[0];

      // Initialize Approval spreadsheet for editing
      // Also open the  Procurement Approvals
      var approvalsSpreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.openById(APPROVALS_SPREADSHEET_ID);
      var approvalsSheet = approvalsSpreadsheet.getSheets()[0];

        // Open the Second Procurement Approvals
     var approval2sSpreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.openById(APPROVALS2_SPREADSHEET_ID);
     var approval2sSheet = approval2sSpreadsheet.getSheets()[0];

      // Open the Third Procurement Approvals
     var approval3sSpreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.openById(APPROVALS3_SPREADSHEET_ID);
     var approval3sSheet = approval3sSpreadsheet.getSheets()[0];

      // Fetch all the data from the Procurement Request Spreadsheet
     var data = getRowsData(sheet);

      // Fetch all the data from First Approvals spreadsheet
      // GetRowsData creates a searchable 2D array 
      var approvalsData = getRowsData(approvalsSheet);

       // Fetch all the data from Second Approvals spreadsheet
      var approval2sData = getRowsData(approval2sSheet);

       // Fetch all the data from Third Approvals spreadsheet
       var approval3sData = getRowsData(approval3sSheet);

      // For every procurement request
      // Iterate through 2D array of Procurement Request (Responses) sheet data
      for (var i = 0; i < data.length; ++i) {
       var row = data[i];
        row.rowNumber = i + 2; 

        // If State field is empty then this a newly submitted request
        if (!row.state) {
         // This is a new request
          // Email the Supervisor to Request his / her Approval

          sendReportToSupervisor(row);
           sheet.getRange(row.rowNumber, COLUMN_STATE).setValue(row.state);
               } else if (row.state == STATE_SUPERVISOR_EMAIL) {

          // If the request has already been sent to the Supervisor then iterate through
          // Check if the Supervisor has accepted or rejected the request in the Approval spreadsheet

          for (var j = 0; j < approvalsData.length; ++j) {
          var approval = approvalsData[j]; 

            // If current request is not the same as the last request id number
            // Then don't stop
            if (row.rowNumber != approval.procurementRequestId) {
              continue;
            }

            // Send approval results to requestor notifying Supervisor's decision
            sendApprovalResults(row, approval);

          // Put Supervisor's email in state field to mark it as being sent to Supervisor for approval
          sheet.getRange(row.rowNumber, COLUMN_STATE).setValue(row.state);

    // Send Approval Request to Manager
      if (row.state == "APPROVED"){

    sendReportToManager(row);
           sheet.getRange(row.rowNumber, COLUMN_STATE2).setValue(row.state2);
         // Put Supervisor's email in state field to mark it as being sent to Supervisor for approval
               } else if (row.state2 == STATE_MANAGER_EMAIL) {

             // Update the state of the report to APPROVED or DENIED
           sheet.getRange(row.rowNumber, COLUMN_STATE2).setValue(row.state2);

      if (row.state2 == "APPROVED"){
         // Send final Approval Request to Director

        sendReportToDirector(row);
           sheet.getRange(row.rowNumber, COLUMN_STATE3).setValue(row.state3);

         // Put Director's email in state field to mark it as being sent to Supervisor for approval
               } else if (row.state3 == STATE_DIRECTOR_EMAIL) {

             // Update the state of the report to APPROVED or DENIED
           sheet.getRange(row.rowNumber, COLUMN_STATE3).setValue(row.state3);

            // Stop if the request id number and current request id are the same. This means there
            // are no new requests to check
          break;
         }
        } 
       }
```

Comment: Is this a coding question? If so please provide what you have tried.

Comment: this is what i have tried so far